# remove FixedLeading in first line of every page itext 7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
doc.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
for (int i = 0; i <20 ; i++) {
    Paragraph element = new Paragraph("p " + i);
    if(i!=0) {
        element.setPadding(0);
        element.setMargin(0);
        element.setFixedLeading(255);
        doc.add(element);
    }
}
```

[image: the output of the program]

How do I remove the indent from the top of the first line?

Answer (score 0):

You don't draw the first line (for `i=0`) at all, so for all lines you do draw you have explicitly set a leading.

To also draw the first line, move the `doc.add` out of the `if` body:

```java
for (int i = 0; i <20 ; i++) {
    Paragraph element = new Paragraph("p " + i);
    if(i!=0) {
        element.setPadding(0);
        element.setMargin(0);
        element.setFixedLeading(255);
    }
    doc.add(element);
}
```

Comment: if if have a big text? AND н wont remove on each page. How can i do it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I pointed out the error in your code. Do you mean the code you posted is not related to your issue?

Comment: The code is not relevant to the problem. i have a big text, and i need to remove FixedLeading on the first line on every page. help please

Comment: Then please share the relevant code. Because such leading does not occur by default.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64195180/remove-fixedleading-at-the-first-line-on-each-page . help