# Remove FixedLeading at the first line on each page

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I want to remove `setFixedLeading` at the first line on each page (100+)

I read a bit text(more 100 page with help while). And  I set padding and margin  to 0 but I  still have top indent. Why? Help me pls? How delete it?

```
public static final String DEST = "PDF.pdf";
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    doc.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
    for (int i = 0; i <20 ; i++) {
        Paragraph element = new Paragraph("p " + i);
        element.setPadding(0);
        element.setMargin(0);
        element.setFixedLeading(55);
        doc.add(element);
    }
    doc.close();

}
```

PDF file:
https://pdfhost.io/v/Byt9LHJcy_PDFpdf.pdf

[image: First page:]

[image: Second page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of element creation you don't know the page it will end up on nor its resultant position. I don't think there is a property that allows you to configure the behavior depending on whether it's the top element on a page (such property would be too custom and tied to a specific workflow).

Fortunately, the layout mechanism is quite flexible and you can implement the desired behavior in a couple of lines of code.

First off, let's not use `setFixedLeading` and set the top margin for all paragraphs instead:

```
Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument);
doc.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Paragraph element = new Paragraph("p " + i);
    element.setPadding(0);
    element.setMargin(0);
    element.setMarginTop(50);
    doc.add(element);
}
doc.close();
```

This does not pretty much change anything in the visual result - it's just another way of doing things.

Now, we need a custom renderer to tweak the behavior of a paragraph if it is rendered at the top of the page. We are going to override `layout` method and check if the area we are given is located at the top of the page - and if so, we will not apply the top margin:

```
private static class CustomParagraphRenderer extends ParagraphRenderer {

    Document document;

    public CustomParagraphRenderer(Paragraph modelElement, Document document) {
        super(modelElement);
        this.document = document;
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new ParagraphRenderer((Paragraph) modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
        if (layoutContext.getArea().getBBox().getTop() == document.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize().getHeight()) {
            ((Paragraph)getModelElement()).setMarginTop(0);
        }
        return super.layout(layoutContext);
    }
}
```

Now the only thing we need to do is to set the custom renderer instance to each paragraph in the loop:

```
element.setNextRenderer(new CustomParagraphRenderer(element, doc));
```

Visual result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, but when I use setFixedLeading, the height of the letters is taken into account, but when margin is not, can I fix it somehow? – gafebLive 12 mins ag